# How to perform validation on selected db connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am making a desktop windows application which basically selects a database , connection string now I want to perform some checks on the selection made , how would I go about doing this?.

I need to check if the database contains specific table names.

Here is my code so far.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> databaseName = GetDatabases();
        if (databaseName.Any())
        {
            cboxDatabases.DataSource = databaseName;               
        }
    }

    private List<string> GetDatabases()
    {
        List<String> databases = new List<String>();

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connection.DataSource = "localhost";
        // enter credentials if you want
        //connection.UserID = //get username;
        // connection.Password = //get password;
        connection.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        String strConn = connection.ToString();
        //create connection
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        //open connection
        sqlConn.Open();

        //get databases
        DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConn.GetSchema("Databases");

        //close connection
        sqlConn.Close();

        //add to list
        foreach (DataRow row in tblDatabases.Rows)
        {
            String strDatabaseName = row["database_name"].ToString();
            databases.Add(strDatabaseName);
        }
        return databases;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public bool TableExists(SqlConnection sqlConn, string tableName) 
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT count(*) as 'Exists' FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[{0}]')", tableName);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);

    int tableResult = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    return tableResult == 1;
}
```

Comment: @user1259076 That is c#. It's using an sql query to determine whether the table exists...

Comment: @user1259076 Before you close your connection, you'll need to run this code for every table you want to check against. I'd suggest making a separate method to do so, see my edit.